# Angular 4: Web API call mapping not working. ProgressEvent returned with error

Tags: angular

I am trying to call a web api end point using code like this.

```
verifyUserLogin(userName: string, password: string): Observable<UserSession>
{
    let observable = this._http.get(this.baseUrl + "?userName=" + encodeURIComponent(userName) + "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(password));
    return observable
        .map(this.convertResponseToUserSession)
        .do(data => this.logData(data))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

The conversion function in the map call is as follows.

```
private convertResponseToUserSession (res: Response)
{
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || { };
}
```

Using fiddler I get the following RAW response.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcUHJvamVjdHNcU05DQ2xpZW50c1xTTkNDbGllbnRzXGFwaVxVc2Vy?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 09 May 2017 17:49:52 GMT
Content-Length: 465
{"id":"c384bf34-6bbc-45a9-944f-6d2d4f7874af","lastAccess":"2017-05-09T14:18:39.7111621-04:00","userId":"arsalan","displayName":"Arsalan","emailAddress":"Arsalan@mycompany.com","employeeId":"3123123","compnayAddressNumber":123123,"departmentAddressNumber":123123,"homeDepartmentAddressNumber":123123,"lineId":0,"phoneNumber":"123-456-7890","companyName":"My Corporation","homeDepartment":"Information Technology","managerName":"My Manager"}
```

For the class

```
export class UserSession {
    public Id: string;
    public lastAccess: Date;
    public userId: string;
    public displayName: string;
    public emailAddress: string;
    public employeeId: string;
    public compnayAddressNumber: number;
    public departmentAddressNumber: number;
    public homeDepartmentAddressNumber: number;
    public lineId: number;
    public phoneNumber: string;
    public companyName: string;
    public homeDepartment: string;
    public managerName: string;

    isSessionValid () : boolean
    {
        if(this.Id && this.Id.length === 36)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The function convertResponseToUserSession never gets called, only handleError is called.

```
private handleError(error: any)
{       
    ...
}
```

where error is a Response object and erorr.toString() return "‌Response with status: 0  for URL: null" and error.json() returns ProgressEvent

The function verifyUserLogin is being called from a  submit event handler as follows.

```
loginUserClicked(): void
{
    this.formWaiting = true;
    this._userService.verifyUserLogin(this.userName, this.password)
        .subscribe((userSession: UserSession) =>
    {
        if (!userSession)
        {
            alert(`Username or password is incorrect.`);
            return;
        }
        this.userAuthenticated.emit(userSession);
    }, (error) =>
    {
        this.errorMessage = <any> error;
        alert(`There was an error trying to log you in. Please contact support.`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Where do you use `verifyUserLogin`?

Comment: It's a <form> submit event handler. I have updated the question.

Comment: I think this might be a cors issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520209/angular-2-exception-response-with-status-0-for-url-null and solving: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790051/how-to-create-cross-domain-request-angular-2

Comment: @AJT_82: It was a CORS issue. The extension resolved it. Please put your response as an answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Done! :) You are very welcome, glad to hear it got sorted out! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error

```
"‌Response with status: 0 for URL: null"
```

would point to a CORS issue, as per said here: [Angular 2: EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0 for URL: null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520209/angular-2-exception-response-with-status-0-for-url-null)

CORS needs to be enabled on server side, and in some cases also enabling cors in the browser itself (during development). This can easily be done with chrome extension available [**here**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi).

And if you are using Firefox, you can use the plugin for FireFox: [**cross-domain plugin**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cross-domain-cors/)

Comment: This error should mention CORS, as it's not clear this is the reason...