# Angular read json file from s3

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to read json file data from s3 bucket with public access for parse data and display in a html table.

```js
http.get<Post>('https://jsonfile/file.json').subscribe    (res => {   
      console.log(res);
    });
```

I have this error:

```
ERROR
HttpErrorResponse {headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null…}
```

This is my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kwn1zg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likey due to CORS issues. Find more information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43878862/6942210).

If you're using this URL it works:

https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://temporal.s3.amazonaws.com/limites.json

```
http
  .get<Post>("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://temporal.s3.amazonaws.com/limites.json")
  .subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

So you have to enable CORS for your S3 Bucket to solve this issue properly.